# Python list comprehension on two list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am stuck with list comprehension in Python

I have the following data structure

```
dataset = [sentence1, sentence2,...]
sentence = [word1, word2,...]
```

in addition, I have a list of special words

```
special_words = [special_word1, special_word2, special_word3,...]
```

I want to run over all special_words in `special_words` and fetch all `words` that occur together in sentence with `special_words`.

As result I expect,

```
data=[special_word1_list, special_word2_list, ...],
```

,where `special_word1_list = [word1, word2, ...]`

it means `word1, word2 ,...` were in the sentences together with `special_word1_list`

I tried many difference ways to construct the list comprehension, unfortunately without any success.

I would appreciate any help, in addition if you know any good article about list comprehension, post it here.

Comment: Could you provide an example? It's a bit unclear if you're after sentences that have a word that's special, or if you're just after words in a sentence that are special... etc....

Comment: Quite ambiguous question. Please provide a clearer example.

Comment: When you say _"`word1`, `word2` ,... were in the sentences together with `special_word1_list`"_ do you mean _"`word1`, `word2` ,... were in the sentences together with `special_word1`"_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = [
    {
        word
        for sentence in sentences
            if special_word in sentence
                for word in sentence
    }
    for special_word in special_words
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
data = [sentence for sentence in data
        if any(word in special_words 
               for word in sentence)]
```

Comment: all words in a sentence should be there, you get only special.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I'd suggest creating a dictionary mapping special words to sets of other words occurring in the same sentence as the respective special word:

```
{sw : {w for ds in dataset if sw in ds for w in ds if w != sw}
      for sw in special_words}
```